# Can Firebase Phone Authentication be used simply for device-ownership verification?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase in a react-native project, and I want to incorporate an SMS one-time-pin while in the registration process. I don't want to use Phone Number Authentication for login purposes. Is this possible and how can it be done if so? If not, what are recommended options for an SMS OTP service?

Edit: *phone number ownership verification*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication only validates that the end user owns the phone number that they entered.  It says nothing about the device they used to sign up.  They could easily remove the SIM card, sell the original device, put the SIM card in another device, and sign in again with no trouble.

Recommendations for offsite resources, including services and products, is off-topic for Stack Overflow, so you should do a web search or ask in another forum in order to find alternatives.